# Dynamic ui:include in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I have this code in JSF:

```
<ui:include rendered="#{paginaMB.pagina eq 'login'}" id="paginaSistema" src="/login.xhtml" />
<ui:include rendered="#{paginaMB.pagina eq 'noticias'}" id="paginaSistema" src="/noticias.xhtml" />
```

I don't know why using "rendered" both pages are displayed.

If I use this code:

```
<ui:include id="paginaSistema" src="#{paginaMB.pagina}.xhtml" />
```

the problem was solved but I have a button inside `login.xhtml` that uses `managed bean` and the `managed bean` is not found, no action is taken when I click on it.

How can I solve this dynamic include?

Answer (score 2):

ui:include doesn't have attribute `rendered`

You should use ui:fragment.

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{paginaMB.pagina eq 'login'}">
  <ui:include id="paginaSistema" src="/login.xhtml" />
</ui:fragment>
```